# Page jumps to top after click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hi I am using a `gravity form` for my `WordPress` website. In this form there is a button `Next` and `Previous` so whenever i do click on `Next` button, first it goes on top and then load the page. I don't want it to go on top, i just want it to load the page. I google it and apply some solution but it is not good enough for me

I used this method

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".button"),
pd = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

};

links.addEventListener('click', pd, false);
```

and:

```
    var links = $('.button');
links.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Can be used anywhere
});
```

But it isn't work for me. This is the [link](https://promo.inkgility.com/shop-2/modern-creative/#_form_168) of my page where this form exist
Any type of help will be appreciate

Comment: The previous and back buttons are `input type='button'` elements not `a` tags. And clicking them reloads the page. That causes the scroll.

Comment: So is there any way to solve this Because i don't want it to go on top

Comment: @ErsinBasaran You mean to say there is no solution for that thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your gravity form with AJAX enabled.  Include ajax=true in your gravity form embed shortcode, and this should prevent the entire page from reloading, instead just the next section of the form will reload.

read more about it here:
https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/multipart-form-without-page-reload